# Java 9, Axis 2, TLS 1.2 handshake_failure

Tags: java, apache-axis, tls1.2

I'm getting "handshake failed" error aftet ServerHelloDone, when trying to connect to WCF service via TLS 1.2 from Java 9 using Axis 2.

**handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

Can't find the reason for this failure. Please help.

Please find communication log bellow.

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2),     SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
update handshake state: certificate_request[13]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
check handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
update handshake state: server_hello_done[14]
upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client     authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
update handshake state: certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 171, 113, 57, 2, 16, 39, 153, 61, 250, 34, 205, 172, 88, 46, 149, 20, 44, 178, 29, 249, 55, 142, 171, 174, 101, 213, 232, 238, 151, 107, 118, 38, 175, 51, 241, 156, 255, 38, 178, 247, 146, 195, 235, 221, 100, 63, 103, 195, 255, 34, 68, 90, 103, 236, 160, 137, 118, 50,     70, 199, 148, 243, 105, 228 }
update handshake state: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 77 63 F4 DE FB EB 6C 73   E7 53 D0 4D 50 3B FD DA  wc....ls.S.MP;..
0010: B1 09 0F 15 AF 6A 6B 54   AB 23 AD 4D 30 B4 55 30  .....jkT.#.M0.U0
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 7F 8F 99 FB F2 4A 62 01   87 56 92 0B 6F 4F A2 70  .....Jb..V..oO.p
0010: 59 D1 B4 56 F8 D9 75 D2   2C 6D 93 2D 50 49 F4 91  Y..V..u.,m.-PI..
Server Nonce:
0000: 47 08 C7 73 56 A2 7F 55   27 46 BA 0F CF 75 41 9A  G..sV..U'F...uA.
0010: A3 38 28 4A 97 31 AE 40   4D 4C CF 5E 83 79 97 3D  .8(J.1.@ML.^.y.=
Master Secret:
0000: A4 DB 8C 4D 93 E0 E0 E6   C7 F8 DA C1 3A A6 9C B4  ...M........:...
0010: A3 A4 8E 84 C1 CF 96 ED   20 14 52 1F 21 77 79 74  ........ .R.!wyt
0020: A9 4A 0C 57 F1 54 68 3F   2C 61 14 81 C3 35 B7 69  .J.W.Th?,a...5.i
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 87 F0 E0 E5 7E 06 0A FA   37 80 E0 74 84 96 49 70  ........7..t..Ip
Server write key:
0000: 51 30 DE 8C DD 1E 85 CE   9F 99 89 5A E6 66 79 E3  Q0.........Z.fy.
Client write IV:
0000: 35 BC 1C 44                                        5..D
Server write IV:
0000: 30 73 A7 9E                                        0s..
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 32, 61, 33, 66, 185, 169, 34, 164, 205, 88, 60, 58 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 24
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-5, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received         fatal alert: handshake_failure
```